# Find a Polar Equation for an Ellipse from Eccentricity

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, polar-coordinates

**Eccentricity: $0.0542$**

**Major Axis Length: $2.854 * 10^9$**

For this particular problem my issue is figuring out how to determine which elliptic equation to use with the givens in the prompt.

My professor provided us with the equation:

$$r = \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos(\theta)}$$

but the solution to the homework assignment on Slader says to use:

$$r = \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1-e\cos(\theta)}$$

How do I determine which elliptic equation to use?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the right focus to be at the origin, use the + sign.

If you wan the left focus to be at the origin, use the - sign.